# Feathers button enable property

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, starling-framework

I am trying to find a way to disable a button in feathers UI (Starling) just like spark button.

```
button:Button = new Button()
button.enabled = false;
this.addChild(button);
```

im just doing it by the moment removing the listener, but i would like to know if there is a more elegant way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try [isEnabled](http://feathersui.com/documentation/feathers/core/FeathersControl.html#isEnabled) property?

Comment: Thank you! this is the correct approachment. I was dealing with the touchable property that makes the button disabled, but dont give the disabled skin to the button. Once again, thanks.